Ensuring dependencies in poetry pyproject.toml use numpy < 2.0 recursively
I'm currently managing dependencies in a Python project using Poetry, and I need to ensure that all dependencies, including their transitive dependencies, do not use numpy version 2.0 or higher. Specifically, I'm concerned about libraries like Prophet inadvertently pulling in numpy 2.0.
Could someone please advise on how to patch my pyproject.toml file so that every listed dependency and their sub-dependencies are restricted to numpy versions strictly below 2.0? This needs to be applied recursively to avoid any library upgrading numpy beyond this threshold.
Thank you!
I've tried specifying numpy directly with numpy = 1.26.4 in my pyproject.toml file, but this approach only limits the top-level numpy version and doesn't prevent sub-dependencies from upgrading to numpy 2.0.

There can be only one installation of a Python package in any given Python environment. If your project specifies numpy < 2 then this constraint is going to be valid for the whole environment.

I managed to resolve the issue by identifying a compatibility issue in DataBricks related to the cluster version. Although the error message did not explicitly indicate this as the problem, upgrading from the Databricks Runtime Version 11.3 LTS to 14.3 LTS completely resolved the issue.
